# Best practices to manage password for embedded Linux devices

Tags: linux, password-management, ssh, embedded-system

Should we generate a strong password offline, keep it closely guarded secret, and use the same one across all copies of the device? The boot drive is eMMC flash soldered on the PCB, hard to read bypassing the OS. Or should I write code that on the first boot changes the password to salted hash of the device serial number? Or is there other well-known practices?

The device has networking, but Internet connectivity is optional and we’d like to keep it that way, it should work without internet, not even connected to any networks at all.

Currently, we don’t know if we ever need to ssh into the device, but I expect it would be useful to fix things. While developing the embedded software, I use ssh and scp all the time, to deploy new builds, read logs, and more. The device is heavy and expensive, replacing gonna cost us too much. I’d like ssh access, or something similar, as an escape latch to manually fix the software if it breaks after it’s delivered to users.

Comment: Why not use public key authentication? You could easily generate key pairs for each device and store the private keys on a server.

Comment: make it only configurable if a button is held down for 30 seconds.

Comment: @drewbenn We gonna sell them. Already selling much simpler ones, with embedded firmware which runs without OS or networking. This question is about providing support after the sale. I can enable SSH daemon when user checks “enable remote assistance” in the settings, the new hardware has a touch screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should we generate a strong password offline, keep it closely guarded secret, and use the same one across all copies of the device?

Absolutely not. There are two primary problems which make the risk (likelihood x impact) of an attack high:

1. The first is that you are likely underestimating likelihood: It is very hard to keep something a secret *in your own company*. It is nearly impossible to do so in the field. For example, it is simple enough to dump the contents of eMMC using physical means. See [1](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/wednesday/us-17-Etemadieh-Hacking-Hardware-With-A-$10-SD-Card-Reader-wp.pdf).
2. The second relates to the impact. If you used a different secret per device, an attacker would have to do an eMMC dump (for example) for *each* device, which is extraordinarily hard to scale. However, if only one secret is used, then every device can be compromised with no extra effort (i.e. the work effort for the attacker is constant, rather than linear w.r.t targets).

> should I write code that on the first boot changes the password to salted hash of the device serial number

This makes things slightly better, but not by much.

If the salt is shared across all devices, you have a problem very similar to what I previously described: an attacker simply needs to do a memory dump **one** time and all devices become vulnerable (a serial number is obviously not cryptographically strong) so best practice is to assume an attacker will be able to take the (shared) password and the (shared) salt, guess the serial number and compute the correct password per target device with little effort.

Using a **unique** salt per device is a definite improvement assuming you **don't store the actual password anywhere** (only store the salted hash). This means you shouldn't "change the password [on first boot]" as suggested. Doing so provides some window of opportunity for an attacker to dump memory and get the password before first boot. At which point, every device is again vulnerable.

> is there other well-known practices?

You can mitigate most of the above issues by relying on public-key cryptography. Generate a private/public key pair in your back office for each device, place the public key on the device file system and the private key in some back office "key management system".

To login, you essentially "sign" some piece of data (using the private key) and send this to the device. The device verifies it using the stored (unique) public key. SSH already supports this, see [2](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/).

## Analysis

Now let's look at the likelihood and impact of an attack:

**Goal**: Prevent malicious attacker from logging into to device over SSH.

**Likelihood:** An attacker can not log in without presenting a proper private certificate (which amounts to guessing a sufficiently long key: impractical) OR by tampering with the device's memory to replace the public certificate OR due to a software implementation bug in the login procedure.

Option 1 is impractical. Option 2 is possible, albeit somewhat time consuming and not scalable. Option 3 is perhaps the most likely, but hard to avoid unless disabling SSH is allowable.

**Impact:** The analysis here is easy. Since we have a unique key pair assigned to each device, an attacker who does any amount of work to crack or change the key pair for a target device will NOT be able to reuse the work on other targets. Let's call the impact of this "low"

Given this our risk is likelihood x impact = low/medium x low = ~ low risk

Of course, you really need to tune your risk model / tolerance to your organization and application. If, for example, these devices are used to control a safety-critical feature of an airplane or car, you may not tolerate even one-time, physical attacks.

## Extra resources

It may be helpful to also review NIST's many guidelines for key management: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Key-Management/Key-Management-Guidelines

Specifically, Chapter 10 of part [3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57Pt3r1.pdf).

## References

1: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/wednesday/us-17-Etemadieh-Hacking-Hardware-With-A-$10-SD-Card-Reader-wp.pdf

2: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/

3: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57Pt3r1.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, was really helpful. About salted serial, we manufacture these devices, we can ensure the first boot happens before we ship the device to customers, and that it erases the salt. We test them anyway. Disabling SSH is OK. Gonna disable by default, only enable when user checks “remote assistance” in the settings.
I’ll try to implement public key crypto, but not sure management will like it. Developing, securing and running that back office server ain’t free. I’m a desktop & embedded developer (made embedded software for the device), have limited experience with web servers.